# Should I manage my async tasks or let container to do so (servlets 3)

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

With `request.startAsync()` you get `asyncContext` that you can `start()`. From there, servlet container manages the lifecycle of passed `Runnable`, while the original thread finishes and it is returned to the pool.

Should I rely on servlet-container management of my `Runnable`s OR it would be better to create (for example) a context-scoped `Queue` and to use eg fixed thread pool of executors to process created `asyncContext` (without actually starting them)?

This way I would have more control of the async work and configurable threads (i dunno if you can configure that on servlet container by the spec?)

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that you need to deal with the resulting Runnables yourself, by passing them to an Executor / ExecutorService. This isn't something that the servlet container will handle for you.

By asking for an AsyncContext, you are essentially telling the servlet container not to retain a thread to handle this request, and you wrap the eventual response generation that would have been performed (in the old synchronous world) in a Runnable with the AsyncContext. At this point, it is up to you to see that the Runnable gets run, and the response generated. But how it gets executed is up to you: queuing, priority, thread pool size, etc.

I'd say something like a ThreadPoolExecutor with a Queue would work well. That way, if you want to start to reject requests once the current in-progress number reaches a certain size, you can choose how to do that yourself (service overloaded response, or similar).